# removing index.php in codeigniter (works fine locally but not on the production)

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I've spent much time searching for an answer but found nobody with the same issue :).

My local version is fine (running on ampps), the urls without index.php are working great. 
My local and prod folders are both in subfolders so it's like :

```
http://localhost/ci/
http://website.com/cms_ci/
```

But when I put my folder on the prod server, the homepage is working but if I want to reach http://website.com/cms_ci/content/ I'm getting a 404. 
If I go on http://website.com/cms_ci/index.php/content/, it's working.

Here are the settings of my config and htaccess files :

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/cms/'; 
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

HTACCESS

```
Options -Indexes
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets/|robots\.txt)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Of course on my prod config file I've changed

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/cms/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.website.com/cms_ci/';
```

I tried all kind of htaccess files but now I'm kinda stucked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check htaccess is allowed or not on your server configuration ..

Comment: here is some link you can look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234289/verify-if-htaccess-file-is-running

Comment: mod_rewrite is in "Loaded Modules" when I'm doing a phpinfo();.
But when I insert junk code in my htaccess I don't have a 500 error...

Comment: check the permission of your htaccess file

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Comment: If you put in junk without a 500 error, `allowoverride` isn't turned on.  Check the `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: was this ever solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried that but that doesn't change anything.
I still can go to the homepage and to others pages when I use website.com/index.php/controller/.
And I've still 404 when I'm trying website.com/controller/

Comment: try with: website.com/index.php?/controller/

Comment: whatever I put as url after the index.php? (webiste.com/index.php?/controller/) I'm going to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|img|images|js|fonts|assets|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

This should work!