# How to force php to use `application/json` without using the explicit command?

Tags: php, json, .htaccess, http-headers, mime-types

We want to create some kind of api where the json formatted results are generated using `.php` files.

The web folder looks like

```
api
├── .htaccess
└── foo
    ├── bar.php
    └── baz.php
```

Where `bar.php` and `baz.php` are php files generating json-formatted replies on the queries.

Such files (`bar.php`) look like:

```
<?php
include_once("../../utils.php");

$id = $_GET['id'];

echo json_encode(some_function($id));
?>
```

Of course one should specify a header `header("Content-type: application/json");`. We however want to set the `.htaccess` to do this, such that one never forgets to set the content-type, that if additional headers are required, we can modify this easily, etc. **We don't want to write `header(...)` in every file**.

`.htaccess` look like:

```
#All php files return JSON formatted text.
AddType application/json json php
```

But the generated result has still mime-type: `text/html`.

What can cause this?

Comment: AddType application/json .json .php

Comment: @TheStatehz: doesn't work :(.

Comment: try - AddType application/json .php - this is the syntax. Ensure your .htaccess file is being used also.

Comment: @TheStatehz: Tried this as well (together with a lot of variations). According to the *Apache* docs, both were valid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234289/verify-if-htaccess-file-is-running

Comment: @TheStatehz: Yup it is running, junk results in a `500`...

Comment: @TheStatehz: found it, this had something to do with default `.php` values such that the header was overwritten. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has some values including [`default_mimetype`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-mimetype). When the Apache server generates the `.php` page, it first sets the `application/json` mime-type, but when the PHP engine starts, the header is modified back to `text/html`. You can set this by adding an additional rule to `.htaccess`:

```
#All php files return JSON formatted text.
AddType application/json json php
php_value default_mimetype application/json
```

Comment: The `AddType` was added by the OP, so that can be ignored I think.

Comment: it works just by writing php_value default_mimetype application/json

Comment: @Ivanzinho: yes correct, but the two other lines originate from the OPs `.httaccess`.