# RewriteRule for a single .php page in a sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a joomla website. Recentley I added a subdirectory to the root of the website which contains some pages which are not linked to the CMS in any way.

I wanted to remove the .php from the end of these pages as I was  going to promote them over social media and wanted the URL's to be easier for users to remember.

The page in questions is:

http://www.mytestwebsite.com/share/thepage.php

So I added the following rule to my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^/share/thepage?$ /share/thepage.php  [NC]
```

With the hopes that the URL would be http://www.mytestwebsite.com/share/thepage 
and still load thepage.php but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^share/thepage/?$ /share/thepage.php  [NC,L]
```

No leading `/` in the first RewriteRule argument in htaccess.
And `/?` is for the optional trailing slash (not optional `e` with `e?`)

Comment: That's not working for me! I literally copied and pasted what you had there

Comment: I have these lines in my `.htaccess` `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^`share/thepage/?$ /share/thepage.php  [NC,L]` and still no joy.

Comment: Are you sure that the .htaccess file is used ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234289/verify-if-htaccess-file-is-running

Comment: I try your page. And that work for me without .php !

Comment: Hi Croises yes it worked. I positioned the code above my other 301 redirects and it worked fine! thank you for your help