# Unable to remove index.php in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, config

I want to remove index.php to access my controllers directly. However, I cannot directly go my controller. I have to use index.php. For example: I want to go
http://example.com/my_controller/method instead of http://example.com/index.php/my_controller/method

By the way, I used my test server, not local server like XAMPP. I enabled apache mod rewrite in my server.

I tried a lot of htaccess rules, conditions but I cannot work it. Please help me!

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

my config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

How can I go directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: First of what version of codeigniter are you using and what localhost xampp, wamp etc

Comment: I use my server to test it.

Comment: If your using wamp make sure you have enabled apache mod rewrite. And make your your htaccess is in main directory out side of application folder.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 No, I dont use it since I use my test server, not a local server. Also, I enabled apache mod rewrite in my server and I tried main directory.

Comment: @cale_b I tried all of answers but It cannot work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about verifying that mod_rewrite is actually enabled.  You could follow the instructions here:  [How to check whether mod_rewrite is enable on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server)

Comment: Yes, I checked and it is enabled. The image link is http://pasteboard.co/P513xT9.png

Comment: How about removing the If statement...  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Comment: How about testing rewrite by following these instructions to intentionally to get HTTP 500 error.  That should prove it is working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234289/verify-if-htaccess-file-is-running

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: did you restart the server after change the .htaccess

Comment: Yes, I did. If I did not restart it, I couldn't see the module in loaded modules by using phpinfo()