# error 500 occures when using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use an htaccess file to route the url requests. my htaccess codes are:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^lang=(.*)$    [NC]

    RewriteRule ^([^.*]+)/?$    ./index.php?url=$1&lang=%1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([^.*]+)/?$    ./index.php?url=$1&lang=en [L,QSA]
```

I use it before on another host and that worked correctly but now I moved the website to another host and I getting a 500 error.
How can I solve this? thanks...

Comment: What url is causing 500error?

Comment: @starkeen the root of site: http://teckala.ir/

Comment: Do you have any other rules on the file?

Comment: @starkeen no, it's all of my htaccess content

Comment: Are you sure the rewrite module is enabled?

Comment: @starkeen yes. it's enabled. however if it was disabled so, the 'RewriteEngine On' instruction will enable it

Comment: Sirvan, You have to enable it using AllowOveride directive on server.config file. RewriteEngine just turns on the engine for rewriting urls

Comment: Read this post on how to debug htaccess

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234289/how-to-debug-htaccess-rewriterule-not-working

Comment: thanks. but i use cpanel. and i can't access to the apache settings. can i do that using cpanel?

Comment: Check your server's error log

Comment: First of all you need to look at the phpinfo() and you will see whether the module is switched on or not.
To enable module from the cPanel you must have admin privileges in the cPanel.
From regular account you can not do this.