# Permalinks doesn't work when overriding .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-hosting

Trying to build a website (not wordpress), using php... want to override .htaccess file for making Permalinks. I wrote the following, but it doesn't works. I use utf-8 encoding. Hosting on NameCheap hosting. Please help.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^laptops/$ https://example.com/categories.php?category=$1 [R=301,L]
```

### From the Main file, I am calling categories.php, using the following link:

```
<a href="/categories.php?category=<? echo strtolower($row1["subcatname"]); ?>" class="card-link" ><? echo $row1["subcatname"]; ?> </a>
```

### Categories.php has the following code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] == 'laptops') {
        echo $_GET['category'] ;
    }
?>
```

.htaccess has the following script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^laptops/$ https://onlibest.com/categories.php?category=$1 [R=301,L]
```

My expectation :
https://example.com/categories.php?category=laptops, should be shown to the user as following Permalink
https://example.com/laptops

Comment: Show the original link and what you expect as a result.

Comment: Updated my question, hope I am clear now

Comment: So, basically I want :
https://example.com/categories.php?category=laptops, should be shown to the user as following Permalink
https://example.com/laptops

Comment: mod_rewrite rewrites the URLs of incoming requests. It does not change what URLs your HTML code links to in the first place - that is something _you_ need to change.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure **mod_rewrite** is enabled and **htaccess** files allowed in your Apache configuration.

Then, put this code in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ categories.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Should work for :

```
example.com/categories.php?category=laptops

to

example.com/laptops
```

Comment: I checked that already and htaccess is readable... I had tried this script before also, but it doesn't works... Does it have anything to do with encoding ? I use utf-8 encoding for saving .htaccess.... (just a small info.  I once changed the encoding, and that corrupted the file. Later I changed back to utf-8)... not sure if that is causing the issue...

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: How do I check that on a Shared Hosting ? I couldn't locate httpd.conf file on their file server

Comment: When you request the url https://example.com/laptops what you get?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234289/how-to-debug-htaccess-rewriterule-not-working it may help you

Comment: I get the following URL : https://example.com/categories.php?category=laptops

Comment: I checked the link : however, as I said I am making a website on a Shared Hosting, where we have shared resources with others. I don't have dedicated server. I can't restart apache etc.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh `<a href="/categories.php?category=<? echo ....` - You need to actually change the links in your HTML source (as @CBroe mentioned in comments above). And `<?` is not a valid opening PHP tag.